# C++ Template Matching both Container and Content

Tags: c++, templates

Having this class

```
template <template <typename> typename Container, typename Content>
class Test final
{
public:
  Container<Content> m;
};
```

An example of how to use the class would be `Test<std::vector, int> test;`

How should `Test` look like in order to be able to use the class like this `Test<std::vector<int>>` and match both Container and Content?

Later Edit:
What if Container has multiple levels like `std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>`, how do you match a type which has 1+ encapsulations over it.

Comment: You wouldn't directly match the element type. Just do `template <typename T>`, then `typename T::value_type` is your element type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks! I'm searching for something more generic, I added a `Later Edit`

Comment: That would be [`std::ranges::range_value_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t).

Comment: Thanks, please add it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `template <typename T>` (possibly constrained with [one of those concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ranges#Range_concepts)).

Then you can get the element type as [`std::ranges::range_value_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t).